# Limiting file type to txt with BlazorInputFile

Tags: blazor, blazorinputfile

I am using BlazorInputFile and I am having trouble figuring out how to filter my file type to just accept txt files

```
async Task HandleSelection(BlazorInputFile.IFileListEntry[] files)
{
    try
    {
        var file = files.FirstOrDefault();
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (file.Type != "application/text")
            {
                PopupModel = new PopupModel
                {
                    Message = "Please select .txt file.",
                    MessageType = MessageType.Info,
                    Show = true
                };
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it client side like you would with an HTML file input.

```
<InputFile accept=".txt" OnChange="HandleFileUpload"></InputFile>
```

Caution: your idea of what's an acceptable file and Chrome or Firefox's is not guaranteed to be the same.  Depending on what you're doing with the file, you might want to check it programmatically-- for example, if your text file contains query strings or html markup or something.

Comment: I think this is not really helpful, since the questioner really wanted to know the C# code how to check the file MIME type correctly. The HTML trick with accept option can easily be overriden by user input (i.e. simply select "all files" in the selection window) or browser.